# Xamarin iOS Push Notifications Not Working

Tags: ios, xamarin, push-notification

I'm using the Xamarin iOS TodoList Azure Sample. [the sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-xamarin-forms-get-started-push)
The App compiles and runs, but does not ask to enable push on start, and push does not work.

It's looks properly configured. 
I am using the device, not emulator.
I am not using wild * card.
I added remote-notification to the info.plist.
The certificate is uploaded to azure.
The bundlename looks good.

Not sure what else to check.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Did you update sertificate in your project on your computer? It started asking for me after that.

Now i get it to ask, can register from backend but can't get anything notified even from test send on azure (it says that it sends to one device but nothing comes through). So if you manage to get notifications, i would really like to know how :D